# How can I make R use more CPU and memory?

Tags: r, cpu-usage

No matter how intensive the R computation is, it doesn't use more than 25% of the CPU. I have tried setting the priority of the `rsession.exe` to `High` and even `Realtime` but the usage remains the same. Is there any way to increase the CPU usage of R to utilize the full potential of my system or is there is any misunderstanding in my understanding of the problem? Thanks in advance for the help.

P.S.: Below is a screenshot of the CPU usage.
[image: Screenshot of the CPU usage]

Comment: Do you have 4 cores? Check the "performance" tab, is 1 core at 100%?

Comment: What are your computer's specs? What version of R are you using?

Answer (score 20):

Base R is single-threaded so that 25% of usage is expected on 4-core CPU. On a single Windows machine, it is possible to spread processing across clusters (or cores if you like) using either the **parallel** package and the **foreach** package.

First of all, the parallel package (included in R 2.8.0+, no need to install) provides functions based on the snow package - these functions are extensions of `lapply()`. And the foreach package provides an extension of for-loop construct - note that it has to be used with the **doParallel** package.

Below is a quick example of k-means clustering using both the packages. The idea is simple, which is (1) fitting `kmeans()` in each cluster, (2) combining the outcomes and (3) seleting minimum `tot.withiness`.

```
library(parallel)
library(iterators)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# parallel
split = detectCores()
eachStart = 25

cl = makeCluster(split)
init = clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(MASS); NULL })
results = parLapplyLB(cl
                      ,rep(eachStart, split)
                      ,function(nstart) kmeans(Boston, 4, nstart=nstart))
withinss = sapply(results, function(result) result$tot.withinss)
result = results[[which.min(withinss)]]
stopCluster(cl)

result$tot.withinss
#[1] 1814438

# foreach
split = detectCores()
eachStart = 25
# set up iterators
iters = iter(rep(eachStart, split))
# set up combine function
comb = function(res1, res2) {
  if(res1$tot.withinss < res2$tot.withinss) res1 else res2
}

cl = makeCluster(split)
registerDoParallel(cl)
result = foreach(nstart=iters, .combine="comb", .packages="MASS") %dopar%
  kmeans(Boston, 4, nstart=nstart)
stopCluster(cl)

result$tot.withinss
#[1] 1814438
```

Further details of those packages and more examples can be found in the following posts.

- [Parallel Processing on Single Machine I](http://jaehyeon-kim.github.io/2015/03/Parallel-Processing-on-Single-Machine-Part-I)
- [Parallel Processing on Single Machine II](http://jaehyeon-kim.github.io/2015/03/Parallel-Processing-on-Single-Machine-Part-II)
- [Parallel Processing on Single Machine III](http://jaehyeon-kim.github.io/2015/03/Parallel-Processing-on-Single-Machine-Part-III)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the changes are to be brought in the program instead of the R configuration? Is there any way that R can be configured to use all the cores?

Comment: `detectCores()` in the parallel package identifies # clusters available on a machine. The above example is done on 4-cored laptop and its single thread equivalent is `kmeans(Boston, 4, nstart = 100)`. Instead of running the algorithm 100 times sequentially, the parallel version runs 25 times at each cluster. Then the results are combined. | As far as I've searched, code has to be modified if the R distributed by CRAN is used. You may search that by Revolution Analytics but I'm not sure.

Comment: Links are dead!

Comment: Links are recovered!

Answer (score 4):

R is, in most cases, single threaded. Unless you set it up properly, you will only use 1 core to 100%. My guess is you are using a quad core machine so 1 core at 100% will look like 25% CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But how can I configure it to use all the cores? I'm using Intel 2nd Gen i5 2440M machine. Do I make changes in the program or configure R in some way?