# How can I make R using more than 1 core (8 available) on a Ubuntu Rstudio server?

Tags: r, lme4, rstudio-server, cpu-cores, rparallel

I want to run the `glmer` procedure in `lme4` package on a large dataset (250,000 observations). The model takes more than 15 min to run on a laptop. We are using a Rstudio server based on Ubuntu. The problem is that 8 cores are available on this server but when I run the `glmer` procedure, only 1 of them is being used and it takes more than 1h to get the results... How can I solve that problem and improve time efficiency? I found on google I may have to use the `parallel` procedure but I am not familiar at all with those informatics procedures and they look very complex to me... Can anyone help with a simple procedure to tackle the problem?

I know they have been questions on the topic already but that was 7 years ago ([R package that automatically uses several cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775098/r-package-that-automatically-uses-several-cores)) or 3 years ago ([How can I make R use more CPU and memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998718/how-can-i-make-r-use-more-cpu-and-memory)). I know R packages and procedures are evolving and I wanted your help on an update on this topic (and hopefully a straightforward, easy solution).

Comment: http://r-sig-mixed-models.r-project.narkive.com/wYRS0KKa/r-sig-me-parallel-version-of-lmer-or-glmer

Answer (score 1):

something like the following would help?

```
library(parallel)
f <- function(i) {
  lmer(Petal.Width ~ . - Species + (1 | Species), data = iris)
}
cls <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterEvalQ(cls, library(lme4))
mod <- parLapply(cls, 1, f)
stopCluster(cls)
```

Comment: works great by adding one more line: clusterExport(cls, c("DataFrame"),envir=environment())